# My Android no longer receives text messages from an iphone since signing in to imessages on my mac

Tags: messages, android

I have a Mac, running Big Sur. I signed in to iMessages, and sent a message to my wife's iPhone.

Now, messages from her iPhone no longer go to my Android, and I can find no way to stop it from sending to iMessage.

Is this a bug? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally only an iPhone will register your cellular number with Messages, but you can check and deregister it here:

- https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/

Once that’s clear, you have to be sure her app is sending to the phone number and not the email.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ask different. It is possible that your wife's iPhone defaults to your Apple ID/iCloud email account to send you messages instead of to your android number. To distinguish between the two, I would suggest she creates two separate contacts for you, one for your android (i.e. just mobile number with no associated email linked to the contact) and one for iMessages (i.e. your Apple ID/iCloud email account). Label the contacts something like `Wife - iMessage` and `Wife - SMS`. Unfortunately having two seperate contacts on her iPhone, will mean having two separate message conversations with her.

The other suggestion is for her to create a new message (rather than going into her current message conversation with you), then `add contact` and select your name and manually select from the dropdown options your mobile number (in green). See image below:

[image]

This will then return her to the current conversation with you, but it should send as an SMS to your android (she'll notice the send arrow will be green). She will have to do the same procedure each time to manually select your mobile number, rather than defaulting to iMessages. Subsequently, I suggest you follow the first suggestion and set two separate contacts for you on her iPhone. Hope this helps!